# Неправильное отображение картинки 9-patch в сплеше

Tags: android

Картинку 9-patch настроил с помощью утилиты draw9patch, идущей вместе с android sdk. Утилита показывает, что рисунок растягивается, как мне надо.

Сплеш изображение активирую в манифесте:

```
    <!-- Splash screen -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/logo"/>
    <!-- Splash screen -->
```

Картинку logo.9.png размещаю в drawable-nodpi. При запуске приложения картинка отображается, но растягивается не так как надо. Вместо исполнения правил разметки 9-patch получается обычное пропорциональное растягивание во всю ширину и высоту.

В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Где картинка?  Как разметил и что должно получиться

Comment: судя по комментарию 
https://forum.qt.io/topic/38925/qt-on-android-working-example-of-a-splash-screen/3
nine patch в сплеше не поддерживается

"The only drawback is that you for some reason can't use Android Layouts as splash screens - but that's a different topic."

Comment: оформите как ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

судя по комментарию [forum.qt.io/topic/38925/…](https://forum.qt.io/topic/38925/qt-on-android-working-example-of-a-splash-screen/3) nine patch в сплеше не поддерживается "The only drawback is that you for some reason can't use Android Layouts as splash screens - but that's a different topic."